# how do I set quad buffering with jogl 2.0

Tags: processing, jogl

I'm trying to create a 3d renderer for stereo vision with quad buffering with Processing/Java. The hardware I'm using is ready for this so that's not the problem.
I had a stereo.jar library in jogl 1.0 working for Processing 1.5, but now I have to use Processing 2.0 and jogl 2.0 therefore I have to adapt the library.

Some things are changed in the source code of Jogl and Processing and I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to tell Processing I want to use quad buffering.

Here's the previous code:

```
public class Theatre extends PGraphicsOpenGL{
protected void allocate()
  {
    if (context == null)
    {
      // If OpenGL 2X or 4X smoothing is enabled, setup caps object for them
      GLCapabilities capabilities = new GLCapabilities();
      // Starting in release 0158, OpenGL smoothing is always enabled
      if (!hints[DISABLE_OPENGL_2X_SMOOTH])
      {
        capabilities.setSampleBuffers(true);
        capabilities.setNumSamples(2);
      }
      else if (hints[ENABLE_OPENGL_4X_SMOOTH])
      {
        capabilities.setSampleBuffers(true);
        capabilities.setNumSamples(4);
      }


      capabilities.setStereo(true);

      // get a rendering surface and a context for this canvas
      GLDrawableFactory factory = GLDrawableFactory.getFactory();

      drawable = factory.getGLDrawable(parent, capabilities, null);

      context = drawable.createContext(null);
      // need to get proper opengl context since will be needed below
      gl = context.getGL();
      // Flag defaults to be reset on the next trip into beginDraw().
      settingsInited = false;

    }
    else
    {
      // The following three lines are a fix for Bug #1176
      // http://dev.processing.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=1176
      context.destroy();
      context = drawable.createContext(null);
      gl = context.getGL();
      reapplySettings();
    }
  }
}
```

This was the renderer of the old library. In order to use it, I needed to do size(100, 100, "stereo.Theatre").
Now I'm trying to do the stereo directly in my Processing sketch. Here's what I'm trying:

```
PGraphicsOpenGL pg = ((PGraphicsOpenGL)g);
pgl = pg.beginPGL();
gl = pgl.gl;
glu = pg.pgl.glu;
gl2 = pgl.gl.getGL2();

GLProfile profile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2);
GLCapabilities capabilities = new GLCapabilities(profile);

capabilities.setSampleBuffers(true);
capabilities.setNumSamples(4);
capabilities.setStereo(true);

GLDrawableFactory factory = GLDrawableFactory.getFactory(profile);
```

If I go on, I should do something like this:

```
drawable = factory.getGLDrawable(parent, capabilities, null);
```

but drawable isn't a field anymore and I can't find a way to do it.
How do I set quad buffering?

If I try this:

```
gl2.glDrawBuffer(GL.GL_BACK_RIGHT);
```

it obviously doesn't work :/

Thanks.

Comment: Good to see The Boss (not Springsteen) picked up coding.  Have you poked around in the Processing opengl package source?  http://code.google.com/p/processing/source/browse/trunk/processing/core/src/processing/opengl/

Comment: Yes I've tried but it's too low level for me, I'm not a jogl expert. Thanks for the link btw